# I am unable to insert ":" in a tag xml, follow example

Tags: xml, vbscript

When creating an XML file using VBScript I am unable to insert ":" in a tag, follow example.
The main difficulty I'm facing is creating a tag in the XML that contains ":" the expected value should be:

I need to generate a tag according to the pattern below

[image]

but I can't generate this tag with ":" between "form" and "Documents"

[image: value achieved wrong=formDocuments]

can someone help me with this, follow my code

```
'By default, the result of this rule is false (document is not going to Exceptions)
Result.CheckSucceeded = false

'If the document is unprocessed or unrecognized 
if me.DefinitionName = "" then
    
    'Routing the document to Exceptions
    Result.CheckSucceeded = true
    
    dim NameFile, ExportPath, objFilename, HeaderText
 
    'Path for notification XMLs
    ExportPath = "\\DELL_NOTEBOOK\prd\Output\"
    
    'Original document name (full path)
    NameFile = me.Pages.Item(0).ImageSource
    objFilename = split(NameFile,"\")
    
    'Original document name (short)
    NameFile = objFilename(ubound(objFilename))
    
    'Text Header
    HeaderText = "Form:Document"

    'XML creation 

Set xmlDoc = createObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") 

Set objRoot = _
  xmlDoc.createElement("formDocuments") 
xmlDoc.appendChild objRoot 

Set objRecord = _
  xmlDoc.createElement("NFSe2_NFSe2") 
objRoot.appendChild objRecord 
  
Set objName = _
  xmlDoc.createElement("_Recusar")  
objName.Text = "true"
objRecord.appendChild objName  

Set objName = _
  xmlDoc.createElement("_DoctoInvalido")  
objName.Text = "SIM"
objRecord.appendChild objName  

Set objDate = _
  xmlDoc.createElement("_id")  
objDate.Text = NameFile 
objRecord.appendChild objDate  

Set objIntro = _
  xmlDoc.createProcessingInstruction _
  ("xml","version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'")  `your text`
xmlDoc.insertBefore _
  objIntro,xmlDoc.childNodes(0) 
xmlDoc.Save ExportPath + NameFile + ".xml" '"\\DELL_NOTEBOOK\Output10\Audits.xml"  
end if
```

Comment: Please don't post the XML as images.  [edit] your question and add it as text, and format it as a code block.

Comment: Dijkgraaf 
I'm sorry, I'm still getting used to this portal

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for `createElement` in the MSXML SDK DOM reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757047(v=vs.85) stating clearly:

> You cannot create a namespace-qualified element using the
> createElement method. Regardless of whether a namespace prefix is
> included in the tagName parameter*,* the namespaceURI property for the
> new element node is set to an empty string, "". An element node
> constructed as part of an XML document load operation will never have
> both a prefix and an empty namespace Uniform Resource Identifier
> (URI). You can only create a namespace-qualified element using the
> createNode method of the DOMDocument object.

So any element node you want to create in a certain namespace with MSXML needs to be created with e.g. `createNode(1, "form:Document", "http://www.abbyy.com/FlexiCapture/Schemas/Export/FormData.xsd")`, i.e. using `createNode` with the type number 1 for element node as the first argument, the qualified named as the second and the namespace URI as the third argument.

Comment: Martin Honnen Thank you very much for your help, the problem has been successfully resolved. I apologize here for my lack of knowledge. Thank you very much.

Comment: Perfect:   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <form:Document xmlns:form="http://www.abbyy.com/FlexiCapture/Schemas/Export/FormData.xsd">
- <NFSe2_NFSe2>
  <_Recusar>true</_Recusar> 
  <_DoctoInvalido>SIM</_DoctoInvalido> 
  <_id>Image_3.tif</_id> 
  </NFSe2_NFSe2>
  </form:Document>